# Measure frequency using timer input capture with STM32

Tags: timer, stm32, capture

I am using STM32F429 MCU. I want to measure a 40 MHz frequency. Is it possible to measure that using Timer1 input capture? (Timer clock is 160 MHz)

Comment: Measure how precisely? Do you need to tell if it's 39MHz or 41MHz? Or to tell if it's 39.95MHz or 40.05MHz?

Comment: 39 MHz or 41 MHz

Comment: Timer clock 160MHz means APB clock is 80MHz, System Clock 160MHz? I don't see it work even remotely without DMA, and you get only 4 measurements per one 40MHz period. So the best theoretical accuracy, if DMA works out, is something like telling 30MHz and 40MHz apart. We're talking about square wave, right?

Comment: Yes, but since the answer will be 4 your quantization error will be 25%.
I'd recommend external clock mode, then count many cycles of the external clock compared to a linked timer clocked by the internal clock.

Comment: You'll also need the STM32 clock to be super accurate. If you use the HSI clock, then it won't be. I had a project last year using the internal clock on an STM32 and the RTC was drifting by several minutes per day.